# How to retrieve data from ebay getFeedback API

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am trying to get some data for a specified user using ebay's getFeedback API and ended up with this code.

```
namespace one
{
class Program
{
    private static ApiContext apiContext = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ApiContext apiContext = GetApiContext();

        GeteBayOfficialTimeCall apiCall = new GeteBayOfficialTimeCall(apiContext);

        GetFeedbackCall call = new GetFeedbackCall(apiContext);
        call.UserID = "abc";

        Console.WriteLine(call.GetFeedback().ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static ApiContext GetApiContext()
    {

        if (apiContext != null)
        {
            return apiContext;
        }
        else
        {
            apiContext = new ApiContext();


            apiContext.SoapApiServerUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment.ApiServerUrl"];
            ApiCredential apiCredential = new ApiCredential();
            apiCredential.eBayToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserAccount.ApiToken"];
            apiContext.ApiCredential = apiCredential;

            apiContext.Site = SiteCodeType.US;

            return apiContext;
        }
    }
}
}
```

It prints the following line in console

> eBay.Service.Core.Soap.FeedbackDetailTypeCollection

How can I get the original data?

Answer (score 1):

call.GetFeedback() returning collection of FeedbackDetailType members, so you can use foreach to retrieve informations (such as feedback score and other stuff) about all particular feedback.

see complete members list of FeedbackDetailType members
[here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/WindowsSDK/docs/LibRef/eBay.Service.Core.Soap.FeedbackDetailTypeMembers.html)!

e.g

```
foreach (FeedbackDetailType feedback in call.GetFeedback())
{
       Console.WriteLine(feedback.CommentText);
       //and other stuff
}
```

Or you can use something like that

```
    call.GetFeedback();
    Console.WriteLine(call.FeedbackScore);
```

Comment: Trying to get feedback for userid "buy", from this [link](http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&ftab=FeedbackAsSeller&userid=buy&iid=-1&de=off&interval=0&items=200). But it returns nothing. I mean the FeedbackDetailType collection is empty